# figuring out end of row in a worksheet

Tags: epplus

I use EPPlus to read a worksheet. In this worksheet, the data I need is in columns `B-D`. In column `A` there are static values, that I would ignore. The values in col `A` are filled in till `Row 1000`. But, the data I need will be there only till, say for example `Row 450`. Currently I use

```
int endRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
```

to calculate the last row to read, but that returns me a value of `1000`. Is there a way for me to get the value of endRow to be `450`, ignoring col `A`?

Answer (score 8):

here is an alternative, it should be a bit more efficient as it counts back from the last row

```
int colB = 2;
int colD = 4;

int lastRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
while(lastRow >= 1) {
    var range = sheet.Cells[row, colB , row, colD ]
    if(range.Any(c => c.value != null))) {
        break;
    }
    lastRow --;
}
```

Comment: It depends entirely on the state of the table - if you take OP's example where 450 is the first empty row, this method would take 549 cycles rather than 451. The fastest way would be a binary search.

Comment: @AlexFoxGill That doesn't make sense. The OP doesn't want to find the first empty row; he wants to find the last non-empty row. A binary search wouldn't do in either case.

Comment: @Pluto check row 500. If populated, check row 750 - if not, check row 250. Repeat 10 times. You've now found your row.

Comment: @AlexFoxGill What if 1-749 are populated, 750-998 are empty, 999 is populated, and 1000 is empty? Binary search won't find row 999.

Comment: @Pluto see question: *"The values in col A are filled in till Row 1000. But, the data I need will be there only till, say for example Row 450."*

Answer (score 5):

You can alternatively check if the value is null.

```
if(worksheet.cells[row,column].value != null)
   {
         //ok to proceed
   }
```

Comment: How can i check if the entire row is empty?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Linq query to get the info you need.

```
using (ExcelPackage exPackage = new ExcelPackage(aFile))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet sheet = exPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

            List<String> checkCol = new List<String>();
            checkCol.Add("B");
            checkCol.Add("C");
            checkCol.Add("D");

            int longestColumn = 0;

            foreach (String col in checkCol)
            {
                var cells = from c in sheet.Cells[col + ":" + col]
                            where c.Value != null & c.Text.ToString() != ""
                            select c;

                if (cells.Count() > longestColumn) longestColumn = cells.Count();

            }


            MessageBox.Show("The endpoint is: " + longestColumn.ToString());
        }
```